# Curl is not accepting localhost from linux , but accepting localhost when checked through gitbash

Tags: linux, curl

I have a spring boot application which I bought up through
java -jar  spring-0.0.1 snapshot.jar and running it in backgroung and then hitting the curl command

curl --request GET -H content-type:"application/json" http://localhost:8082/sample

giving me Hi as response which is not the one which I pass from my restcontroller.

But if I am hitting the same from gitbash , i am able to get th eproper response.

FI: curl --request GET -H content-type:"application/json" http://ipv4address:8082/sample is working from linux .

can somebosy pls help me to get this, how to use localhostr with curl from linux script.

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: Can you provide some error messages or unexpected outputs that you are seeing?

Answer (score 0):

can you try this:
http://127.0.0.1:8082/sample instead of  http://localhost:8082/sample

Comment: Tried that also,but getting the same.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the answer, it is because in my unix box the previous java jar was running in background and because of that I was getting the old result every time. I killed that background process and checked , now it is working fine.
Thank you

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).